# ¿Existe algún verbo para definir la acción de realizar trabajos de mecánica?

Tags: definiciones

En varias ocasiones he escuchado a los mecánicos de autos referirse a la acción de hacer revisiones o ajustes a las piezas de un medio de transporte como "mecanear" o "macaniquear", pero estas palabras no existen en el diccionario. He estado buscando durante un tiempo si existe algún verbo que defina esta acción pero no he podido dar con el.

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres una palabra en un diccionario especifico? Ningún diccionario tiene todas las palabras que existen o que sean posibles. Si te entienden, es suficiente, ¿no?

Comment: Vale la pena agregar que en este contexto `Mecanizar` tampoco sería correcto incluso si sí existe.

Comment: @Flimzy es que pense que quizás existiría una palabra quizás para ello, gracias por la aclaración

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El verbo exacto no existe pero hay otro muy útil; `hacer` que puede acompañar al sustantivo

> Hacer mecánica

Si te suena incompleto (a mi no) puedes usar

> Hacer labores de mecánica

Similar a "mecánica" tendríamos "electrónica". Al igual que para el mecánico no existe un verbo para expresar las labores del carnicero, el electricista, el albañil, etc.

Existen seguramente muchos sustantivos que quisiéramos convertir en verbos pero como no siempre es posible o aceptado es necesario usar verbos que representen la acción como hacer, realizar, etc.

Answer (score 2):

En su lugar usaría el verbo apropiado:

> reparar, revisar, construir, montar, mantener, etc.

No se me ocurre ningún verbo que agrupe todo lo anterior. Me recuerda a otra pregunta sobre la palabra *textear*. Algunas palabras son derivadas de la influencia de otras lenguas y no han sido aceptadas por la RAE.